# Cypress command timeout of '10000ms' exceeded

Tags: javascript, cypress

Getting started with Cypress, I'm noticing my test fails about passing:

```
describe('Sessions Page', () => {
  it('Loads', () => {
    // Set up alias
    cy.server()
      .route('POST', '/graphql')
      .as('graphql');

    // Visit site
    cy.visit('/', { timeout: 30000 })
      .wait('@graphql')
      .its('Status')
      .should('be', 200);
  });
});
```

When I run this, it passes, then after a few seconds it fails.

I see this output:

[image]

Another thing I found strange is that the test says Passed immediately but it's still waiting for the route to resolve:

[image]

Comment: I've seen something similar when your `route()` doesn't set any response. I think the stub is then ignored. So try returning even an empty string like `.route('POST', '/graphql', '')`